# Proper way to format Dictionary with multiple entries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am just curious what is the best/most efficient way to structure a Dictionary in Python with multiple entries.  It could be a dictionary of students, or employees etc.  For sake of argument a 'Name' key/value and a few other key/value pairs per entry.

For example, this works great if you have just one student...

```
student_dict = {'name': 'John', 'age': 15, 'grades':[90, 80, 75]}
```

Is this the right way to do it?  One variable per dictionary entry? Somehow I don't think it is:

```
student_1 = {'name': 'Fred', 'age': 17, 'grades':[85, 80, 75]}
student_2 = {'name': 'Sean', 'age': 16, 'grades':[65, 70, 100]}
student_3 = ...
```

I'm sure there is a simple way to structure this where it would be easy to add new entries and search existing entries in one location, I just can't wrap my head around it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dictionary or list to store the dictionaries. Since you seem to want to be able to refer to individual dictionaries by name I suggest a dictionary of dictionaries:

```
students = {'student_1': {'name': 'Fred', 'age': 17, 'grades':[85, 80, 75]},
            'student_2': {'name': 'Sean', 'age': 16, 'grades':[65, 70, 100]}}
```

Now you can refer to individual dictionaries by key:

```
>>> students['student_1']
{'name': 'Fred', 'age': 17, 'grades': [85, 80, 75]}
```

If you don't care about names, or you need to preserve the order, use a list:

```
students = [{'name': 'Fred', 'age': 17, 'grades':[85, 80, 75]},
            {'name': 'Sean', 'age': 16, 'grades':[65, 70, 100]}]
```

Access them by index:

```
>>> students[0]
{'name': 'Fred', 'age': 17, 'grades': [85, 80, 75]}
```

Or iterate over them:

```
for student in students:
    print(student['name'], student['age'], student['grades'])
```

Comment: Thanks @mhawke.  That helps explain it a lot.  Curious though when I run that final for loop I get a "name is not defined" error.  Any ideas?

Comment: @JD2775: sorry, it should be referring to items in the dictionary by key. I have updated the answer to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to choose the key which will give you quick access to a student record. The name seems the most useful:

```
students = {
    'Fred': {'name': 'Fred', 'age': 17, 'grades':[85, 80, 75]}
    'Sean': {'name': 'Sean', 'age': 16, 'grades':[65, 70, 100]}
}
```

Then you can get the record for Fred with `students['Fred']`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should use dictionaries inside of dictionaries. For example:

```
people = {   "John":{"age":15, "school":"asborne high"},
             "Alex":{"age":32, "work":"microsoft"},
             "Emily":{"age":21, "school":"florida state"}   }
```

Using this method, you can efficiently index any value by its name alone:

```
print(people["Alex"]["age"])
```

Second, if you are shooting for readability and ease-of-use, make sure to properly format your multi-dimensional dictionary objects. What I mean by this is you should try to stick to at most two data structures for your custom-objects. If you need to organize a list of dogs, their colors, name, and age, you should use a structure similar to this:

```
dogs = {     "Lisa":{"colors":["brown","white"], "age":4 }, 
             "Spike":{"colors":["black","white"], "age":10}    }
```

Notice how I do not switch between tuples and lists, or dictionaries and lists. Consistence is key.

When organzing numeric data, stick to the same concept.

```
numbers = {     "A":[2132.62, 422.67, 938.2218113, 3772.7026994],
                "B":[5771.11, 799.26, 417.9011772, 8922.0116259],
                "C":[455.778, 592.224, 556.657001. 66.674254323]    }
```